# btree program crashing possibly due to pointers

Tags: c++, b-tree

I'm trying to print a b tree in level order,but it keeps on crashing. Im not sure whats the real reason but i think its crashing because of the pointers. Im trying to use a function i found online that goes through each level and puts it in a queue and prints it, but ive run into this problem.If anyone has another way of doing it please let me know.

```
// C++ program for B-Tree insertion
    #include<iostream>
    #include <queue>
    using namespace std;
    int ComparisonCount = 0;
    // A BTree node
    class BTreeNode
    {
        int *keys;  // An array of keys
        int t;      // Minimum degree (defines the range for number of keys)
        BTreeNode **C; // An array of child pointers
        int n;     // Current number of keys
        bool leaf; // Is true when node is leaf. Otherwise false
    public:
        BTreeNode(int _t, bool _leaf);   // Constructor

                                         // A utility function to insert a new key in the subtree rooted with
                                         // this node. The assumption is, the node must be non-full when this
                                         // function is called
        void insertNonFull(int k);

        // A utility function to split the child y of this node. i is index of y in
        // child array C[].  The Child y must be full when this function is called
        void splitChild(int i, BTreeNode *y);

        // A function to traverse all nodes in a subtree rooted with this node
        void traverse();

        // A function to search a key in subtree rooted with this node.
        BTreeNode *search(int k);   // returns NULL if k is not present.

                                    // Make BTree friend of this so that we can access private members of this
                                    // class in BTree functions
        friend class BTree;
    };

    // A BTree
    class BTree
    {
        BTreeNode *root; // Pointer to root node
        int t;  // Minimum degree
    public:
        // Constructor (Initializes tree as empty)
        BTree(int _t)
        {
            root = NULL;  t = _t;
        }

        // function to traverse the tree
        void traverse()
        {
            if (root != NULL) root->traverse();
        }

        // function to search a key in this tree
        BTreeNode* search(int k)
        {
            return (root == NULL) ? NULL : root->search(k);
        }

        // The main function that inserts a new key in this B-Tree
        void insert(int k);
    };

    // Constructor for BTreeNode class
    BTreeNode::BTreeNode(int t1, bool leaf1)
    {
        // Copy the given minimum degree and leaf property
        t = t1;
        leaf = leaf1;

        // Allocate memory for maximum number of possible keys
        // and child pointers
        keys = new int[2 * t - 1];
        C = new BTreeNode *[2 * t];

        // Initialize the number of keys as 0
        n = 0;
    }

    // Function to traverse all nodes in a subtree rooted with this node
    /*void BTreeNode::traverse()
    {
        // There are n keys and n+1 children, travers through n keys
        // and first n children
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            // If this is not leaf, then before printing key[i],
            // traverse the subtree rooted with child C[i].
            if (leaf == false)
            {
                ComparisonCount++;
                C[i]->traverse();
            }
            cout << " " << keys[i];
        }

        // Print the subtree rooted with last child
        if (leaf == false)
        {
            ComparisonCount++;
            C[i]->traverse();
        }
    }*/

    // Function to search key k in subtree rooted with this node
    BTreeNode *BTreeNode::search(int k)
    {
        // Find the first key greater than or equal to k
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n && k > keys[i])
            i++;

        // If the found key is equal to k, return this node
        if (keys[i] == k)
        {
            ComparisonCount++;
            return this;
        }
        // If key is not found here and this is a leaf node
        if (leaf == true)
        {
            ComparisonCount++;
            return NULL;
        }

        // Go to the appropriate child
        return C[i]->search(k);
    }

    // The main function that inserts a new key in this B-Tree
    void BTree::insert(int k)
    {
        // If tree is empty
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            ComparisonCount++;
            // Allocate memory for root
            root = new BTreeNode(t, true);
            root->keys[0] = k;  // Insert key
            root->n = 1;  // Update number of keys in root
        }
        else // If tree is not empty
        {
            // If root is full, then tree grows in height
            if (root->n == 2 * t - 1)
            {
                ComparisonCount++;
                // Allocate memory for new root
                BTreeNode *s = new BTreeNode(t, false);

                // Make old root as child of new root
                s->C[0] = root;

                // Split the old root and move 1 key to the new root
                s->splitChild(0, root);

                // New root has two children now.  Decide which of the
                // two children is going to have new key
                int i = 0;
                if (s->keys[0] < k)
                {
                    ComparisonCount++;
                    i++;
                }s->C[i]->insertNonFull(k);

                // Change root
                root = s;
            }
            else  // If root is not full, call insertNonFull for root
                root->insertNonFull(k);
        }
    }

    // A utility function to insert a new key in this node
    // The assumption is, the node must be non-full when this
    // function is called
    void BTreeNode::insertNonFull(int k)
    {
        // Initialize index as index of rightmost element
        int i = n - 1;

        // If this is a leaf node
        if (leaf == true)
        {
            ComparisonCount++;
            // The following loop does two things
            // a) Finds the location of new key to be inserted
            // b) Moves all greater keys to one place ahead
            while (i >= 0 && keys[i] > k)
            {
                keys[i + 1] = keys[i];
                i--;
            }

            // Insert the new key at found location
            keys[i + 1] = k;
            n = n + 1;
        }
        else // If this node is not leaf
        {
            // Find the child which is going to have the new key
            while (i >= 0 && keys[i] > k)
                i--;

            // See if the found child is full
            if (C[i + 1]->n == 2 * t - 1)
            {
                ComparisonCount++;
                // If the child is full, then split it
                splitChild(i + 1, C[i + 1]);

                // After split, the middle key of C[i] goes up and
                // C[i] is splitted into two.  See which of the two
                // is going to have the new key
                if (keys[i + 1] < k)
                    i++;
            }
            C[i + 1]->insertNonFull(k);
        }
    }

    // A utility function to split the child y of this node
    // Note that y must be full when this function is called
    void BTreeNode::splitChild(int i, BTreeNode *y)
    {
        // Create a new node which is going to store (t-1) keys
        // of y
        BTreeNode *z = new BTreeNode(y->t, y->leaf);
        z->n = t - 1;

        // Copy the last (t-1) keys of y to z
        for (int j = 0; j < t - 1; j++)
            z->keys[j] = y->keys[j + t];

        // Copy the last t children of y to z
        if (y->leaf == false)
        {
            ComparisonCount++;
            for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
                z->C[j] = y->C[j + t];
        }

        // Reduce the number of keys in y
        y->n = t - 1;

        // Since this node is going to have a new child,
        // create space of new child
        for (int j = n; j >= i + 1; j--)
            C[j + 1] = C[j];

        // Link the new child to this node
        C[i + 1] = z;

        // A key of y will move to this node. Find location of
        // new key and move all greater keys one space ahead
        for (int j = n - 1; j >= i; j--)
            keys[j + 1] = keys[j];

        // Copy the middle key of y to this node
        keys[i] = y->keys[t - 1];

        // Increment count of keys in this node
        n = n + 1;
    }
    void BTreeNode::traverse()
    {
        std::queue<BTreeNode*> queue;
        queue.push(this);
        while (!queue.empty())
        {
            BTreeNode* current = queue.front();
            queue.pop();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (leaf == false)
                    queue.push(current->C[i]);
                    cout << " " << current->keys[i] << endl;
            }
            if (leaf == false)
                queue.push(current->C[i]);
        }
    }

    // Driver program to test above functions
    int main()
    {
        BTree t(4); // A B-Tree with minium degree 4
        srand(29324);
        for (int i = 0; i<200; i++)
        {
            int p = rand() % 10000;
            t.insert(p);
        }

        cout << "Traversal of the constucted tree is ";
        t.traverse();

        int k = 6;
        (t.search(k) != NULL) ? cout << "\nPresent" : cout << "\nNot Present";

        k = 28;
        (t.search(k) != NULL) ? cout << "\nPresent" : cout << "\nNot Present";

        cout << "There are " << ComparisonCount << " comparison." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: When you have a crashing program, run it in a debugger to catch the crash in action. That way you will learn about where in your code it happens, and can also look at the variables involved to help you understand why it might happen.

Comment: One possible source of the problem might be that you seems to allocate memory for `BTreeNode::C`, but you don't initialize each pointer inside the allocated array, leaving its contents *indeterminate*. If you try to use such a pointer it will lead to *undefined behavior* and possible crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your traversal code uses the field values for `this` as though they were the values for the `current` node in the loop body.

You need to stick `current->` in front of the member references in the loop body like this (in the lines marked with "//*"):

```
    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        BTreeNode* current = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < current->n; i++)  //*
        {
            if (current->leaf == false)  //*
                queue.push(current->C[i]);
                cout << " " << current->keys[i] << endl;
        }
        if (current->leaf == false)  //*
            queue.push(current->C[i]);
    }
```

This is a strong indicator that all the stuff qualified with `current->` in reality wants to live in a function where it is `this` and thus does not need to be named explicitly.

Your code is better organised and more pleasant to read than most debug requests we get here, but it is still fairly brittle and it contains quite a few smelly bits like `if (current->leaf == false)` instead of `if (not current->is_leaf)`.

You may want to post it over on Code Review when you have got it into working shape; I'm certain that the experienced coders hanging out there can give you lots of valuable advice on how to improve your code.

In order to ease prototyping and development I would strongly advise the following:

- use `std::vector<>` instead of naked arrays during the prototype phase
- invalidate invalid entries during development/prototyping (set keys to -1 and pointers to 0)
- use `assert()` for documenting - and checking - local invariants
- write functions that verify the structural invariants **exactly** and call them before/after every function that modifies the structure
- compile your code with `/Wall /Wextra` and clean it up so that it always compiles without warnings

Also, don't use `int` indiscriminately; the basic type for things that cannot become negative is `unsigned` (node degree, current key count etc.).

P.S.: it would be easier to build a conforming B-tree by pinning the order on the number of keys (i.e. number of keys can vary between K and 2*K for some K). Pinning the order on the number of pointers makes things more difficult, and one consequence is that the number of keys for 'order' 2 (where a node is allowed to have between 2 and 4 pointers) can vary between 1 and 3. For most folks dealing with B-trees that will be a rather unexpected sight!

Comment: Thanks this helped alot.You have any idea on how i can print the b tree showing each level?I want to show how the whole b tree will look like.

Comment: @user You're welcome. Printing as a text diagram to show the structure is best done via a [breadth-first traversal](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/), perhaps after an initial traversal during which you collect some info needed for formatting (width of padding needed for centring a node above its children) in an auxiliary data structure. However, it would be best if you asked this as a separate question, to get more and better answers. Also, please have a look at the help section to see why [voting and accepting answers is important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).