# Insertion in a B-Tree

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, b-tree

everyone. I'm having a bit of trouble with the implementation of the insert function of a BTree in C. I'm trying to do exercise 18-2.1 from Cormen's book, and I'm following line by line the algorithm contained in the book, but even so, I can't get it to work properly. Here is my code:

```
#define TYPE char

#define T 2
#define NOT_FOUND -1
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


typedef struct _node {
  int n;
  int leaf;
  TYPE keys[2 * T - 1];
  struct _node *child[2 * T];
} Node, BTree;
```

/*-----------------------------*/

```
BTree* createBtree () {
   BTree *a = (BTree *)malloc(sizeof(BTree));
   a->n = 0;
   a->leaf = TRUE;
   return a;
}


void printBtree (BTree *a, int level) {
   int i;


   for (i = 0; i < level; i++) { printf("  "); }


   printf("|");
   for (i = 0; i < a->n; i++) {
      printf("%c|", a->keys[i]);

   }
   printf("\n");


   for (i = 0; i <= a->n; i++) {
      if (a->leaf == FALSE) {
         printBtree(a->child[i], level + 1);
      }
   }
}


BTree* splitNode (BTree *x, int i, BTree *y) {
    int j;
    BTree *z = createBtree();
    z->n = T - 1;

    for (j = 0; j < T - 1; j++){
        z->keys[j] = y->keys[j+T];
    }

    if (y->leaf == FALSE)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < T; j++){
            z->child[j] = y->child[j+T];
        }
    }

    y->n = T - 1;

    for (j = x->n; j >= i+1; j--){
        x->child[j+1] = x->child[j];
    }

    x->child[i+1] = z;


    for (j = x->n-1; j >= i; j--){
        x->keys[j+1] = x->keys[j];
    }

    x->keys[i] = y->keys[T-1];


    x->n++;


   return x;
}

BTree* insertNonFull (BTree *x, TYPE k) {
    int i = x->n-1;

    if (x->leaf == TRUE){

        while (i >= 0 && x->keys[i] > k){
            x->keys[i+1] = x->keys[i];
            i--;
        }


        x->keys[i+1] = k;
        x->n++;


    }
    else
    {
        while (i >= 0 && x->keys[i] > k){
            i--;
        }

        i = i + 1;

        if (x->child[i]->n == 2*T-1){
            x = splitNode(x, i, x->child[i]);

            if (k > x->keys[i]){
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }

        x->child[i] = insertNonFull(x->child[i], k);
    }

    return x;
}


BTree *insert (BTree *root, TYPE keys) {
   BTree *r = root;
   if (r->n == (2*T - 1)) {
      BTree *s = createBtree();
      s->leaf = FALSE;
      s->child[0] = r;
      s = splitNode (s, 0, r);
      s = insertNonFull (s, keys);
      return s;
   }
   else {
      return insertNonFull (r, keys);
   }
}




int main () {

   BTree *a = createBtree();

   a = insert (a, 'F');
   a = insert (a, 'S');
   a = insert (a, 'Q');
   a = insert (a, 'K');
   a = insert (a, 'C');
   a = insert (a, 'L');
   a = insert (a, 'H');
   a = insert (a, 'T');
   a = insert (a, 'V');
   a = insert (a, 'W');
   a = insert (a, 'M');
   a = insert (a, 'R');
   a = insert (a, 'N');
   a = insert (a, 'P');
   a = insert (a, 'A');
   a = insert (a, 'B');
   a = insert (a, 'X');
   a = insert (a, 'Y');
   a = insert (a, 'D');
   a = insert (a, 'Z');
   a = insert (a, 'E');

   printBtree(a, 0);


   return 0;
}
```

It works just fine until I insert 'M' in the tree ("splitChild" is called in two different levels, maybe can be something related to that?). 'T's children doesn't show when I print the tree. I really don't know what to do at this point... I'm stuck and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does someone knows how can I fix the implementation? Those are the results after the insertion of 'W' and 'M'.

**MORE INFO ADDED BELLOW:**

After W (Its ok at this point) [What printBtree shows]:

```
|F|Q|T|
  |C|
  |H|K|L|
  |S|
  |V|W|
```

Representation in a real b-tree:

```
        | F | Q | T |
      /     |    \   \ 
     /      |     \   \ 
    |C| |H|K|L|   |S|  |V|W|
```

After M [What printBtree shows]

```
|Q|
   |F|K|
     |C|
     |H|
     |L|M|
   |T|
```

Representation in a real b-tree:

```
                 | Q |
                /     \ 
               /       \ 
          |F|K|         |T|
         /  | \ 
        /   |  \
      |C|  |H| |L|M|
```

What was supposed to show:

```
 |Q|
   |F|K|
     |C|
     |H|
     |L|M|
   |T|
     |S|
     |V|W|
```

After split function is called in two different levels of the tree (node "H,K,L" and node "F,Q,T"), 'S' and "V,W" disappear from the tree.

Comment: Debugging B-tree code gets a whole lot easier if you can print B-trees in a way that shows their structure. Have a look at the topic [Want to print out a “pretty” btree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829399/want-to-print-out-a-pretty-btree/36848138#36848138) which mentions several options. The code I gave there prints parent nodes centred above their child nodes; it is C++ but transforming it to C should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: The biggest issue is very few, if any have Cormen's book, so without further explanation, nobody know what it is you are trying to accomplish. You need to be clear on what output you expect and how what you get is not what you expect to get.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my first post. I'm editing the post so I can show properly what it should be the final result.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  More info was added now. I think that it has something to do with applying splitChild in a node that already has children, but even so, I can't find what is going wrong.